# Warning: Text content did not match. Warning in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm seeing error messages in my chrome dev tool when I run my NextJS app.

The error message I'm seeing is

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Sign out" Client: "Log In"

The login screen SSR and returned to the client. On the client side the use can see the login button to login. Once successfully logged, this button disappears and a logout button is displayed. This change (removing the login button and replacing it with logout button) is done in the browser so the change is not SSR.

When a user logs in, a cookie is stored in the browser. To replicate the above message all I have to do is clear the cache and reload the page.

The error message does make sense. When cache is cleared and the page is reloaded, the page is server-side-rendered and it will show the login button. the change from login to log out is done in client side.

Is the correct way to handle this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT - example code
This is what the nav looks like

```
    <AppBar component="header" position="static">
  <Toolbar>
    {!userInfo && (
      <Button color="inherit" component={Link} href="/login">
        Log In
      </Button>
    )}
    {!userInfo && console.log("!userInfo", userInfo)}
    {userInfo && (
      <Button color="inherit" component={Link} href="/login">
        Sign out
      </Button>
    )}
    {userInfo && console.log("userInfo", userInfo)}
    <IconButton
      color="inherit"
      aria-label="add to shopping cart"
      component={Link}
      href="/cart"
    >
      <AddShoppingCartIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

I am using redux and redux thunk in the app for global app state management

Comment: Sounds like the most expedient fix is to use two buttons and toggle visibility rather than changing the text content of the button.

Comment: I'm doing that at the moment. I have two buttons but I'm seeing the above behaviour. Ive update above with example of what my code looks like

Comment: A possible solution would be to not render the button on the server-side, and do it exclusively on the client-side.